# Alternative way to reference UI-Bootstrap to AngularJS Project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there a way that I could reference [UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/) to an AngularJS Project without using any Package Manager or alike program? I tried to make a deep search for it but failed to find one.

I tried to download the UI-Bootstrap package from its home site but it somehow needs NPM to be able to add it on a project

Comment: https://unpkg.com/browse/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason you have to use NPM or any other package manager/build-tool, as long as you are willing to manage the dependencies your self. See https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ for dependencies you will need. Then just add the required JS libraries to your index.html file, or webpack/gulp/grunt, whatever. Generally you want the vendor JS files to be include prior to your application JS files. They include a demo, if you want a reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/misc/demo

Answer (score 1):

Use https://unpkg.com/browse/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.module', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ui.bootstrap.ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.ToolTipText = "Hello, World!";
})
```

```html
<link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.module" >
  <div ng-controller="ui.bootstrap.ctrl">

    <span uib-tooltip="{{ToolTipText}}" tooltip-placement="bottom" >
      Hover for Tooltip
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```